# cordova add plugin via git ssh url?

Tags: cordova

I would like to know if there is a way to add cordova plugin through git ssh url.

I have some plugins privately hosted on GitHub. When I initiate the project, cordova will fetch them via https, because I have defined the dependencies in `config.xml` as follows:

```
...
<plugin name="my-plugin" spec="https://github.com/me/my-plugin.git" />
...
```

But I have to type in my username and password every time cordova installs these plugins. So I want to use ssh url.

I have tried to use `git://`. Cordova CLI says it is fetching the repo by cloning, but it does not install the plugin. I also tried using `git@` but that one throws an invalid format error. I also tried writing custom shell scripts and running `cordova plugin add git://...` but it did not work.

I am using the Cordova CLI v5.4.1, latest at the time of writing.

Answer (score 17):

```
cordova plugin add git+ssh://%ssh-link-here%
```

It would look like

```
cordova plugin add git+ssh://git@your.git.server.com/path/to/plugin/repo.git
```

Comment: There is a bug in cordova versions 7.0.2-8.0.0 that prevents adding from ssh like this. If you are on one of these versions, update cordova to 8.0.1 or later.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13507

Answer (score -3):

Its as simple as that, you can add your private plugin hosted in the git to your project via

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/path to your repo /plugin-name.git
```

and then if required edit the config.xml accondingly

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but using `https` is exactly what I *don't* want to do, because it will prompt for username/password.

Comment: Anyone like me getting here that doesn't mind using https, the above answer works. Here's how I just used it: cordova plugin add https://github.com/embarq/PrivacyScreenPlugin.git  <<OUTPUT:
Installing "cordova-plugin-privacyscreen" for android
Android Studio project detected
Adding cordova-plugin-privacyscreen to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-privacyscreen" to config.xml